# Creating overlapping histogram plots

Tags: plotting

I am plotting two histograms on the same graph:

```
g1 = Histogram[bc, ChartStyle -> {Red}]
g2 = Histogram[bcx]
Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.6}, All}]
```

[image]

But I would like the plots to overlap so that they are "see-through" and I can compare them.
I've been trying with

```
ChartStyle -> {"Overlapped"}
```

which hasn't been working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### First method

You could make the one in front partially transparent:

```
bc = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
bcx = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];

g1 = Histogram[bc, ChartStyle -> {Red}];
g2 = Histogram[bcx, ChartStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5]]}];
Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Direct method

The same effect can be achieved by plotting the two distributions in the same plot directly:

```
Histogram[{bc, bcx}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

Comment: Why lead with the more complex solution?!

Comment: @BrettChampion the second one didn't occur to me until after I finished writing the more complex solution.

Answer (score 31):

Doesn't `Histogram` do this already?

```
data1 = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[1, 1.5], 500];

Histogram[{data1, data2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Version 7 doesn't have `HistogramDistribution` as shown by Andy Ross.  Here is an alternative:

```
Histogram[{data1, data2},
  BaseStyle  -> FaceForm[None],
  ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

jmlopez asked for a method without the vertical lines.  Here is one.  The replacement may be a bit fragile.  Andy's method is safer for version 8 users.

*Update: modified to work in Mathematica 10 as well.*

```
h =
 Histogram[{data1, data2},
   ChartStyle -> (Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[3]] & /@ {Red, Blue}),
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
 ];

h2 =
 Histogram[{data1, data2},
   ChartStyle -> {{Red, Blue}, Directive[Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[]]}
 ];

hline = h /. rec : {({{_Rectangle}} | {}) ..} :>
  Line[  Flatten[rec, 2] /. _[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}, ___] :> Sequence[{x, Y}, {X, Y}]  ];

Show[hline, h2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[kjo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2464/kjo) pointed out that my method fails when bars have a height of zero.  The simplest fix I can think of is to avoid zero-height bars (which are not drawn, the source of the problem) by using a small offset value for the *hspec* function.

```
hfn = $MachineEpsilon + #2 &;

h = Histogram[{data1, data2}, {0.1}, hfn, 
  ChartStyle -> (Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[3]] & /@ {Red, Blue}), 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]

h2 = Histogram[{data1, data2}, {0.1}, hfn, 
  ChartStyle -> {{Red, Blue}, Directive[Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[]]}]

hline = h /. 
   rec : {({{_Rectangle}} | {}) ..} :> 
    Line[Flatten[rec, 2] /. _[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}, ___] :> Sequence[{x, Y}, {X, Y}]];

Show[hline, h2]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the middle lines? And get something like [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageHistogram.html) on the second example. I like how they just set the Apperance to Transparent and its done.

Comment: I feel that it is a little absurd how there is tons of examples of how to use `Histogram` and yet there is no option to do what you just did in the update. All it really is is a line plot connecting points with the fill axis property. Anyway, thank you Mr. Wizard.

Comment: There's a problem with the histogram outlining scheme at the end (last plot), when the histogram contains empty bins (not an uncommon situation, especially towards the tails).  To elicit this condition, just add a narrow bin width specification (e.g. `{0.1}`) as a second argument to the `Histogram` expressions.

Comment: @kjo I think I found a relatively simple fix; please take a look and test it for me.

Comment: Your fix is very elegant I think, and it works beautifully.  A couple of thoughts.  Since the offset added by the *hspec* function (`hfn`) is so small, one could omit it from the second histogram (`h2`).  In fact, if one has some time to kill, one could even set `hfn = offset + #2 &`, for some arbitrary positive integer offset, and then change the last subexpression in `hline` from `Sequence[{x, Y}, {X, Y}]` to `Sequence[{x, Y - offset}, {X, Y - offset}]`.  (A probably useless embellishment.)

Answer (score 22):

You also have the option of `SmoothHistogram`.

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^3];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.4, 1], 10^3];

SmoothHistogram[{data1, data2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}]
```

[image]

Or using one of the nonparametric distributions `HistogramDistribution`...

```
Plot[Evaluate[{PDF[HistogramDistribution[data1], x], 
   PDF[HistogramDistribution[data2], x]}], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For g2 you should be able to change the definition to:

```
g1 = Histogram[bcx, ChartStyle -> Opacity[0.50, Blue]]
```

To get the front histogram to be more transparent. Fiddle around with the 0.50 to get it to look the way that you want.