# Overlapping ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

I have two ArrayPlots, and I want to overlap them as it is done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/creating-overlapping-histogram-plots).

For clarity, suppose

```
Array1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}]; 
Array2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}];
```

and the first `ArrayPlot` uses `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White,Yellow},#]&)`, and the second uses `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White,Blue},#]&)`.

I'd like to combine them in such a way I end up with an ArrayPlot with White, Yellow, Blue and Green shades.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Won't the top plot completely block the bottom one? Do you mean set an opacity for top level see-through? - judging by your green color in question.

Comment: There is one big difference between the linked example of overlapping histograms and this question of overlapping array plots: The dimensions of `Array1` and `Array1` are identical, so there is never any _partial_ overlap. For that reason, I can't see why you don't just create a third _new_ array (e.g. the sum) from the two given ones and plot _that_ with the desired color scheme. It would be a much cleaner solution, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, as I must be able to see from which array are some points that can have roughly the same values, i.e. `A1[[1,1]] = 0.5, A1[[1,2]] = 0, A2[[1,1]] = 0, A2[[1,2]] = 0.5`, the sum would be the same, but I'd like the point `(1,1)` to be a shade of Yellow, while the point `(1,2)` to be a shade of Blue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
ImageMultiply @@
 Table[
  ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}], ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, color}, #] &)],
  {color, {Yellow, RGBColor[0, 0.6, 1]}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same operation can be done on the Raster data to preserve full scalability:

```
gr =
  Table[
    ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}], ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, color}, #] &)],
    {color, {Yellow, RGBColor[0, 0.6, 1]}}
  ]

Graphics[
  Raster[gr[[1, 1, 1]]*gr[[2, 1, 1]]],
  Options[gr[[1]]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like this a lot, as it preserves the intensity of the colors. Thanks a lot Mr.Wizard

Comment: @Manuel you're welcome; I like it for the same reason.

Answer (score 7):

Is it something like this?

```
p1 = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}],ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Yellow}, #] &)];
p2 = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}],ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Blue}, #] &)];
Overlay[{p1, SetAlphaChannel[p2, .5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: No `Overlay` nor `SetAlphaChannel` function are on my version of Mathematica (v7.0.1/Linux x64). I suppose working with `ImageCompose` (wich I found thanks to your answer), would somehow be the same.

Comment: @Manuel I am also on version 7.  You could use something like this to get a result similar to Overlay:  `Show[p1, Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], p2[[1]]}]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Tanks again. This tip will be helpful in other situtions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ColorFunction` with a fourth argument in `RGBColor`. This argument sets the transparency of the color. For example, this blends a transparent `Red` (ie white) into full on `Red`:

```
transRed = (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &);
```

Similarly,

```
transGreen = (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1 , 0, 1]}, #] &);
```

Then, you can use these as the `ColorFunction` in an `ArrayPlot` (or `DensityPlot`, etc). For example:

```
redplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}], ColorFunction -> transRed]
greenplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}], ColorFunction -> transGreen]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to overlay them, you can do it with `Show`:

```
Show[redplot,greenplot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why not show this with yellow and blue as the OP requested?  Nevertheless +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Answered on now-closed other question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11565/overlapping-red-and-green-arrayplots-to-show-yellow-intersections/11566#comment35056_11566
and am too busy to re-write ATM.

Comment: This is a great solution also. Thanks!