# Overlapping Red and Green ArrayPlots to show yellow intersections

Tags: graphics, color

Let's say I have two `ArrayPlot[]`s. One is in redscale and the other is in greenscale, such that the lowest value is white and the highest value is pure red or green. How do I overlap the two `ArrayPlot[]`s such that intersections are a combination of red and green to give a yellow intensity dependent on the "red" and "green" values?

**Edit**

I understand that maybe the question is not so clear. I got my idea from a common technique in biology where red fluorescent and green fluorescent signals are captured separately, then merged together.
Areas of red and green together become yellow, but regions of red only or green only are just those colors in the merged image.

I am aiming to translate this to data arranged in arrays such that the final merged image will show areas of red and green "signals" as yellow and red/green alone is still red/green alone.

Example:
[image]

Comment: But those pictures are fully saturated. That's what was confusing us!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ArrayPlot` with 3 dimensional data (i.e. where each element of the 2D array is a pair of values `{r,g}`), and a `ColorFunction` which returns a single colour from such a pair.

In the first example the `ColorFunction` varies the hue continuously from red to green, so that the colour reflects the dominance of red or green in the data. In the second example the Hue is pinned to yellow whenever the data is non-zero in both channels.

Create some data:

```
r = ConstantArray[Flatten[ConstantArray[#, 20] & /@ {0, 1, 0, 0.67, 0, 0.33, 0}], 140];
g = Transpose[r];

GraphicsRow[{
  ArrayPlot[r, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #] &)],
  ArrayPlot[g, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Green}, #] &)]}]
```

[image]

Example 1:

```
rgcol[{r_, g_}] := Hue[1/6 + ((g - r)/(10^-6 + Max[g, r]))/6, Max[r, g], 1];

ArrayPlot[Transpose[{r, g}, {3, 1, 2}], ColorFunction -> rgcol]
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
rgcol[{r_, g_}] := Hue[Clip[Sign[g]/3 - Sign[r]/6, {0, 1}], Max[r, g], 1];

ArrayPlot[Transpose[{r, g}, {3, 1, 2}], ColorFunction -> rgcol]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you nailed it. +1

Comment: The retention of color dominance is extremely informative and useful.

Answer (score 11):

Load your example images:

```
imgF = Import["http://fivephoton.com/image/MultipanelIFbApril2011.png"];
it = ImageTake[imgF, -300, 608];
{r, g, b} =  Join[ImagePartition[it, {304, 300}][[1]], 
                 {Image[Table[{0, 0, 0}, {300}, {304}]]}];
GraphicsRow@{r, g, b}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now see the result of

```
  ColorCombine@Diagonal[ColorSeparate /@ {r, g, b}]
```

Side by side with the desired outcome

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not bad!

Comment: +1 very nice adaptation to the example given.

Comment: @DavidCarraher thanks! It took me some time to understand the OP's need, and only realized it by looking at that example

Answer (score 6):

**Some Data**

Here are two arrays, each of which have about 1/3 of their cells completely white (i.e. zero).

```
t1 = {{0, 0.9879420302163389`, 0, 0, 0.1849135890743674`}, {0.5742726088623453`, 0, 0.7914989802131724`, 0.19955892383000506`, 0.5597205682260553`}, {0.2783414505391293`, 0, 0.9748372906416929`, 0.08279443406565345`, 0.2832336389395025`}, {0.08577104927374801`, 0.7063421364586411`, 0, 0.5527067781783652`, 0.6623671920909151`}, {0.894385628016626`, 0.9220701552898367`, 0, 0, 0}}
t2 = {{0, 0.12518558916583622`, 0.7837612564671677`, 0, 0.3613465765727111`}, {0, 0.5040126862416661`, 0.7678471080216887`,0.8343516601886358`, 0.8591413788042153`}, {0.02105789348188214`, 0, 0.28409400830761267`, 0, 0}, {0.6511904278640404`, 0.5489190727738871`, 0.1852029426833548`, 0, 0.2908999228718716`}, {0.9793706128289879`, 0.5649780777815978`, 0.3898922119375319`, 0.24108312672016763`, 0.03651079793179979`}}
```

`t3` is the sum of `t1`, `t2`, with the constraint that non-zero values are rapped in `r` or `g`, to later be interpreted as red and green.

```
t3 = (t1 /. {x_?NumberQ /; x != 0 :>  r[x]}) + (t2 /. {x_?NumberQ /; x != 0 :>  g[x]}) 
/. {g[x_] + r[y_] :> (x + y)/2, g[x_] :> Blend[{White, Green}, x], r[x_] 
:> Blend[{White, Red}, x]};
```

When red intersects with green, they make yellow (with an intensity that corresponds to the average of their hues); when red intersects with white, red prevails; when green intersects with white, green prevails. (I used `Chop` to ensure that a portion of the cells would remain white. )

`t1` and `t2` are plotted as red and green Arrays.

`t3` is plotted in red, green, white, and yellow (where red and green intersect).

```
a1 = ArrayPlot[t1, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red},#] &), ImageSize -> 150, PlotLabel -> "a1"];
a2 = ArrayPlot[t2, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Green}, #] &), ImageSize -> 150, PlotLabel -> "a2"];
a3 = ArrayPlot[t3, ImageSize -> 150,  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Yellow}, #] &), PlotLabel -> "a3"];
GraphicsGrid[{{a1, a2, a3}}]
```

[image: array plots]

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The question is quite confusing as the text specifies a white-to-color scale while the example is black-to-color.  Nevertheless the example convinces me that indeed `ImageAdd` is what you want.

```
Import["http://fivephoton.com/image/MultipanelIFbApril2011.png"];
{{a, b}, {c, d}} = ImagePartition[%, {304, 300}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row@{c, d, ImageAdd[c, d]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first row requires some adjustment to handle the blue channel as shown.

Either average the blue channels:

```
Row@{a, b, ImageAdd @@ (ImageApply[{#, #2, #3/2} & @@ # &, #] & /@ {a, b})}
```

Or use only the first:

```
Row@{a, b, ImageAdd[a, ImageApply[{#, #2, 0} & @@ # &, b]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You may find utility in ImageAdd.  It would be helpful if you more clearly defined the overlap behavior that you desire.

```
Table[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, color}, #] &)], {color, {Red, 
   Green}}]

ImageAdjust[ImageAdd @@ %, {0, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All sorts of transformation are possible depending on what you want:

```
Table[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, color}, #] &)], {color, {Red, 
   Green}}]
Image[Plus @@ (ImageData[#, "Real"] & /@ %)/2]
ImageApply[{1, 1, 0} (1 - 2 Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]) &, %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this is exactly the right idea; you just need to use `Blend[{Black,color},#]&` instead of `White` for your example to show the results the OP wants.

Comment: @Rahul yes, thank you.  The question is confusing because it explicitly states *white*.  I'm still not sure if the OP wants that or not so I left it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ColorFunction` with a fourth argument in `RGBColor`. This argument sets the transparency of the color. For example, this blends a transparent `Red` (ie white) into full on `Red`:

```
transRed = (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &);
```

Similarly,

```
transGreen = (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1 , 0, 1]}, #] &);
```

Then, you can use these as the `ColorFunction` in an `ArrayPlot` (or `DensityPlot`, etc). For example:

```
redplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}], ColorFunction -> transRed]
greenplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}], ColorFunction -> transGreen]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to overlay them, you can do it with `Show`:

```
Show[redplot,greenplot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, this is a good example, EXCEPT the heart of my question is how to specifically get YELLOW intersections where red and green intersect. "Stronger" overlap (defined by red and green addition) yields a "stronger" yellow color.

Comment: Ah, whoops. Missed that.

Comment: Since this isn't what the question asked for and you've written the same answer at the right place (the other question), I would suggest deleting it (or correcting it), as it might be misleading. :)

Comment: @rm-rf yeah, i know. hopefully i'll try to fix it this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps :

```
 t1 = Table[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}];
 t2 = Table[(x - Pi)^2 + (y - Pi)^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}];

 Panel@GraphicsRow[
   ArrayPlot[#[[1]], ColorFunction -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
                                       {{t1, (Hue[1,   1-#, 1] &)},
                                        {t2, (Hue[1/3, 1-#, 1] &)},
                                        {Total[Rescale/@ {t1, t2}], (Hue[1/8, 1-#, 1] &)}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]