# Make good looking histograms from frequency data

Tags: plotting

I allways do my calculations in *Mathematica* and I make my histograms using [ROOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT) language. However I am wondering is it possible to make good looking histogram inside *Mathematica*? A sample of what I mean is the following figure (made by ROOT):

[image]

Some sample data (not identical to the one used in the above plot) which can be used:

```
data = {154.081, 468.999, 648.538, 776.386, 899.310, 766.234, 596.229, 527.160, 443.315, 
        300.393, 216.542, 105.620, 53.7748, 29.0068, 21.4696, 8.92971, 8.63114, 5.70516, 
        60.5296};
```

using as the red pluses inside histogram and

```
montecarlo = {180.836, 492.187, 739.735, 894.031, 915.812, 841.874, 699.237, 556.588, 
              426.208, 303.230, 212.114, 133.295, 71.6399, 36.9657, 21.9234, 9.20245,
              6.13829, 5.20975};
```

using as the best fit to the data. Note that both data sets are final frequency values and not the original data set on which `Histogram` could work.

Comment: You can draw such plots using the `ListPlot` command. There are many options for color, style, etc. To get the plus signs, you would use the option `PlotMarkers`. You can access the help files for these commands using `?ListPlot`

Comment: @bill s Thanks a lot for your comment. What about the other joined plots? I guess that I can't make them using `ListPlot` and I don't know that `Histogram` can produce them or not.

Comment: @Zahra actually this is not a histogram with the traditional meaning its more like a _step plot_.

Comment: Of course you can make them with Mathematica. But you need to learn how to use the documentation. `?` is your friend.

Comment: I note that not all pluses have the same size. Apparently they are error margins. Shouldn't that be incorporated as well?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries indeed, I think `ErrorBarPlots`might be of help ...

Comment: If you want functionality of `Histogram` itself (rather than precalculated bins) you might find the answers here useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2279/121

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard Thanks a lot. Although I asked my question after visiting this link to become sure that my question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
g1 = Plot[montecarlo[[Floor[n + 1]]], {n, 0, Length[montecarlo] - 1},
          Exclusions -> Solid, PlotRange -> {{0, Length[montecarlo]}, All},
          PlotStyle -> Green];

g2 = ListPlot[Thread[{Array[# - .5 &, Length[data]], data}], PlotMarkers -> Style["+", 18], 
              PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g2]
```

Result:

> [image]

for further formatting of the image, axes, labels, legends look at the online help of Mathematica its very concise.

---

Taking into account Sjoerd C. de Vries' comment in mind, if you want the pluses to corespont to error bar you can use the following commands:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
errors = Abs[PadRight[montecarlo,#]-PadRight[data,#]]&@Max[Length/@{montecarlo, data}]
g2eb = ErrorListPlot[Array[{{# - .5, data[[#]]}, ErrorBar[.5, errors[[#]]]} &, Length[data]], 
                     PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g2eb]
```

> [image]

this is just a demonstration I need more information on what the errors denote for a faithful reproduction of ROOT's plot. If you have the errors as a list just substitute the value of my `error` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is great. Exactly what I was looking for. ;)

Comment: In the OP plot the plot markers are in the middle of the stair steps.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries its a matter of a shifting, I make the change to reflect that. The sample data is different so  the two plots can be qualitatively the same.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify `InterpolationOrder -> 0` in `ListPlot`, and you can specify different orders for different datasets:

```
ListPlot[{montecarlo, MapIndexed[{First@#2 + .5, #1} &, data]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Spacer@0, Style["+", 18]},
  Joined -> {True, False}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
  InterpolationOrder -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]