# Histogram with the smaller bar in front

Tags: histograms, style, opacity

I am trying to visualise multiple data sets in one histogram. When using one or two datasets, the automatic transparency of the bars keeps everything relatively easy to see. When going to three or more datasets however, quickly the colours become confusing and unclear, in particular when there is much overlap.

```
data = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 2], 200], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[6, 2], 200], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[4, 3], 200]};
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}]
```

[image]

Instead of the transparency and the overlay of the colours, one can disable the transparency. The result of this however is that smaller bars can get hidden behind larger ones. Is there a way to make sure that the smallest bar in a certain bin is always in front of the larger ones? I have looked but all I found is the `"Stacked"`  option of `ChartLayout` which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: What about a 3D histogram?  `Histogram3D[MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, data, {2}], ChartStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}]`

Comment: Although neat for use inside of Mathematica, I want to use the plots for reports and presentations as well so a 2D solution would be highly preferable. The closest solution I found is the line method mentioned [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/creating-overlapping-histogram-plots) where only `EdgeForm` is used. Ideally I would have something like that where the bars are filled and ordered front to back from small to large

Comment: A much, much better option (for even just 1 data set) is `SmoothHistogram` (see answer from @AndyRoss at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2316/19758) and/or `SmoothKernelDistribution` (if you want to do more than just display the distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k = Histogram[Tooltip[#, False] & /@ data, ChartStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}]

(k /. {_[_[{_[_[_[{_, RectangleBox[a___]}]], _]}, _], _]} :> Rectangle[a]) /. 
{_[___, _[c : RGBColor[__]]], b : {Rectangle[__] ..}} :> Thread[{c, b}] /.
{{{}, s : {{RGBColor[__], Rectangle[__]} ..}, __}} :> s /.
{s : {RGBColor[__], Rectangle[__]} ..} .. :> s /. 
s : {{RGBColor[__], Rectangle[__]} ..} :> 
                           (SortBy[#, -#[[2, 2, 2]] &] & /@ GatherBy[s, #[[2, 1]] &])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I must confess, I find having this many histograms overlaid in one chart to be quite confusing…

Comment: @J.M. You should take a look at my meeting notes to gain some courage

Comment: Okay, you beat me in the code-golf here lol

Comment: @JasonB Shorter,but no axes `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Cases[k, RGBColor[___] | p : RectangleBox[___], Infinity] /. 
    RectangleBox -> Rectangle //.
   {x___, RGBColor[___], b : RGBColor[__], y___} :> {x, b, y}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: @JasonB Sometimes [Mathematica needs  to be driven like a Ferrari](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Itr0jcR0S4s)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Seriously though would you be willing to "ungolf" that code in your comment? It is so short, and if you just add Frame->True then it does what my big-ass code does. I thought I understood replacement rules and patterns but now I don't think so.  Where in there are you sorting? What do those naked colons do? I'm sure I can look up that "what the @#/ do all these symbols mean?" post, so you don't need to answer, but rest assured I'm impressed.

Comment: @JasonB Perhaps tomorrow. Gotta go-

Answer (score 2):

So I dug up a function I [had written](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103396/9490) to create a custom histogram, and have modified it to do the task here.

```
sortedHistogram[data_, colorlist_, labellist_, 
  plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{bins, bincounts, width, rectangles},
  (* Check that you have given a color and label for each data set *)

    If[Not@SameQ[Length[data], Length@colorlist, Length@labellist],
   Print["List dimensions not equal"];
   Abort[];
   ];
  (*Next we get the bins that would result from doing a histogram on \
the entire data set *)
  bins = HistogramList[Flatten@data][[1]];
  (* Then we get the bincounts for the individual data sets *)

  bincounts = Last@HistogramList[#, {bins}] & /@ data;
  width = First@Differences@bins;
  (* Create an array of rectangles *)

  rectangles = 
   Function[{color, 
      heights}, {EdgeForm[Black], color, 
        Rectangle[{#1 - 0.5 width, 0}, {#1 + 0.5 width, #2}]} & @@@ 
      Transpose[{Mean /@ (Partition[bins, 2, 1]), heights}]] @@@ 
    Transpose[{colorlist, bincounts}];
  (* Then sort them, putting the smallest in front.  
  This involves a transpose, sort, transpose sequence *)

  rectangles = 
   Transpose[
    Sort[#, #1[[3, 2, 2]] > #2[[3, 2, 2]] &] & /@ 
     Transpose[rectangles]];
  (* Now we show the data, and I've included the legend by default *)

    Legended[
   Show[Graphics /@ rectangles, plotopts, Frame -> True, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.7],
   SwatchLegend[colorlist, labellist]
   ]
  ];
```

We'll try it on some test data,

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#1, #2], 300] & @@@ {{2, 
     2}, {6, 2}, {4, 3}, {0, 4}};
```

This is the default histogram,

```
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Purple}]
```

[image]

And here is the sorted histogram,

```
sortedHistogram[data, {Red, Blue, Green, Purple}, {"label1", "label2",
   "label3", "label4"}]
```

[image]

You can give any graphics options to customize the plot,

```
sortedHistogram[data, {Red, Blue, Green, Purple}, {"label1", "label2",
   "label3", "label4"}, AspectRatio -> .5, ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameLabel -> {"value", "frequency"}, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

However, the `BaseStyle` won't apply to the legend labels.  To do that you need to give a `Style` object for the labels.  For example instead of `{"label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"}`, put `Style[#, 18, FontFamily -> "Times"] & /@ {"label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"}`

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your approach is that sometimes the *larger* bar and sometimes the *smaller* bar will be "in front."  As such, I prefer seeing the data in 3D, especially for presentations (I can dynamically rotate the 3D figure for my audience) and reports:

```
z = Table[
   {i, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 2]]}, {i, 3}, {200}];
Histogram3D[z]
```

[image]

You mentioned the difficulty when there are more than three histograms.

Try this:

```
Histogram3D@Table[
  {i, RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[RandomReal[30], RandomReal[10]]]}, 
  {i, 10}, {200}]
```

or better yet:

```
mymeans = RandomReal[{1, 20}, 10];
mystandarddevs = RandomReal[{5, 20}, 10];
myfig = Histogram3D@Table[
   {i, RandomVariate[
     NormalDistribution[mymeans[[i]], mystandarddevs[[i]]]]}, 
   {i, 10}, {200}]
```